# Asp.Net Mvc "Remember Me" not working on server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, cookies, claims

I am developing web application with asp.net mvc.

It's seems to work in local, but in a shared hosting, It last for about 10 minutes then logout.

Here is the code:

```
AccountController.cs

                var claims = new List<Claim>();

                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()));

                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

                var context = Request.GetOwinContext();

                var authenticationManager = context.Authentication;

                authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(90), IsPersistent = true }, identity);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
```

Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            CookieName = "social",
            CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Never
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solving my problem by adding machine key, hope helps someone